# rails serialized array validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, serialization, activemodel

I need to validate email saving in email_list. For validation I have EmailValidator. But I cannot figure out how to use it in pair of validates_each. Are there any other ways to make validations?

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :email_list
  validates_each :email_list do |r, a, v|
    # what should it be here? 
    # EmailValidator.new(options).validate_each r, a, v
  end
end
```

Comment: :email_list is an array containing emails and you want to be sure each email is a valid one or what?

Comment: yes, exactly. I need to validate every email and add error if anyone is invalid

Comment: the answer provided by @gwcoffey seems to do that.

Comment: main difficulty is related to 'if' condition. I cannot figure out how to use EmailValidator here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this:
https://gist.github.com/amenzhinsky/c961f889a78f4557ae0b

You can write your own `EmailValidator` according to [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) and use the `ArrayValidator` like:

```
validates :emails, array: { email: true }
```

Answer (score 5):

`validates_each` is for validating multiple attributes. In your case you have one attribute, and you need to validate it in a custom way.

Do it like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :all_emails_are_valid

   ...

   private
   def all_emails_are_valid
      unless self.email_list.nil?
         self.email_list.each do |email|
            if # email is valid -- however you want to do that
               errors.add(:email_list, "#{email} is not valid")
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Note that you could also make a custom validator for this or put the validation in a proc on the `validate` call. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations).

Here's an example with a custom validator.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

  class ArrayOfEmailsValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      return if value.nil?
      value.each do |email|
        if # email is valid -- however you want to do that
          record.errors.add(attribute, "#{email} is not valid")
        end
      end
    end
  end

  validates :email_list, :array_of_emails => true

  ...

end
```

Of course you can put the `ArrayOfEmailsValidator` class in, i.e., `lib/array_of_emails_validator.rb` and load it where you need it. This way you can share the validator across models or even projects.

Comment: I stick to if condition), what could it be using EmailValidator?

Comment: I added a second example of a custom validator

Comment: Thanks for it. But I still can't find way to use EmailValidator. As it can have complicated logic, which cannot inserted to ArrayOfEmailsValidator directly. Is it possible to write 'if' code in details?